# how to create select box in registration form in joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

how to create select box in registration form in joomla.

I have try to add birthyear in my registration form using dynamic.

option value from 1950 to current year.how to add the year using loops or dynamic code.

Here is my code.

```
<field name="joinyear" type="list"
        description="COM_USERS_REGISTER_JOINYEAR_LABEL"
        filter="string"
        label="COM_USERS_REGISTER_JOINYEAR_DESC"
        message="COM_USERS_REGISTER_JOINYEAR_DESC"
        required="true">
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    <option value="2011">2011</option>
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    <option value="1950">1950</option>
</field>
```

Comment: Hi, as you can see below i wrote a short tutorial how to extend standart joomla form field types, if there are any questions - please dont hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I'd recommend you to create your own list type:
create a directory /models/fields/year.php which will extend JFormFieldList class defined in /libraries/joomla/form/fields/list.php

And add there the following code:

```
<?php
defined('JPATH_PLATFORM') or die;

JFormHelper::loadFieldClass('list');

class JFormFieldYear extends JFormFieldList
{
    protected $type = 'Year';

    protected function getOptions()
    {
        $options = array();         
        $yearNow = date('Y');

        for ($i = 1950; $i <= $yearNow; $i++)
        {
            $tmp = JHtml::_('select.option', $i, $i, 'value', 'text', false);
            $options[] = $tmp;
        }

        reset($options);

        return $options;
    }
}
```

And then in your xml type define type="year" instead of type="list" for a field like this:

```
<field name="joinyear" type="year"
        description="COM_USERS_REGISTER_JOINYEAR_LABEL"
        filter="string"
        label="COM_USERS_REGISTER_JOINYEAR_DESC"
        message="COM_USERS_REGISTER_JOINYEAR_DESC"
        required="true" />
```

Comment: @di3sel : good tutorial but i am created new directory and file in the /models/fields/year.php and also update code in \components\com_users\models\forms\registration.xml file . But i am getting text box only not getting select box

Comment: Make sure that in your registration.xml begins with something like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form>
<fieldset addfieldpath="/administrator/components/COM_YOUR_COMPONENT/models/fields">

You need to add include path in your fieldset declaration.